# SEVERE: Java heap space java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

While fetching records from database I am getting below Error, Could you please any one help me.

Fetching code is

```
session = MySessionFactory.getSession();
            System.out.println(text);
            Query query = session.createQuery("from Visitor where v_firstname =:firstName");
            query.setParameter("firstName", text);
            System.out.println("ch1---");
            return query.list();

Here i got ch1---. It means while fetching records that error is coming.
```

I increased java heap space also to 1024mb,
I am using primefaces 4.0
Below is my log file.

Thanks in advance.

```
Aug 6, 2014 4:17:14 PM org.primefaces.extensions.component.ajaxerrorhandler.AjaxExceptionHandler handlePartialResponseError
SEVERE: Java heap space
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.getBytes(Buffer.java:207)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Buffer.readLenByteArray(Buffer.java:339)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.BufferRow.getColumnValue(BufferRow.java:330)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBytes(ResultSetImpl.java:1935)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBytes(ResultSetImpl.java:1913)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getBytes(ResultSetImpl.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractBynaryType.get(AbstractBynaryType.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:173)
    at org.hibernate.type.AbstractType.hydrate(AbstractType.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2114)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1404)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1332)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1230)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:603)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:724)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:259)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadCollection(Loader.java:2019)
    at org.hibernate.loader.collection.CollectionLoader.initialize(CollectionLoader.java:59)
    at org.hibernate.persister.collection.AbstractCollectionPersister.initialize(AbstractCollectionPersister.java:587)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1744)
    at org.hibernate.collection.AbstractPersistentCollection.forceInitialization(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:476)
    at org.hibernate.engine.StatefulPersistenceContext.initializeNonLazyCollections(StatefulPersistenceContext.java:867)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:264)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2232)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2129)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2124)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:401)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:363)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:196)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1149)
```

Comment: Can you please show us code. What are you doing? What data procession are you doing. Have you debug application to find out where its getting failed. Then post that code snippet.

Comment: I edited my question by add java code. Please see now.

Comment: How many records `Visitor` having?

Comment: Actually Visitor table have 2k records.

Comment: Can you set log level to info and try again, and post log upto error

Comment: Where you are calling `session.clear()` or `session.flush()`

Comment: I am closing session in finally block. So i think no need to clear

Comment: Please any one give the solution, I am fully spruced with this problem, I can not do any work with out solving this problem. Please any one help me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58846/discussion-between-srikanth-and-amogh).

Comment: I am not able replicate your problem at my side, I am able to `list()` more then 8k records. I used same code as you posted.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There is no wrong code in my project.

Problem is, so many wast(unused) objects and list objects are there and all list objects have so many records. I just clean my code and just restarted my system(Server). Now its working fine.

My suggestion is don't fetch total records at any time, **use lazy loading for every time**. If any object is not required for next then assign null to that object then only garbage collector can work.